# C# event which fires at property value change

Tags: c#, properties

Hi I have document class with property Status (e.g doc.Status) and the situation is as follows: when the Status property is set to confirmed I want to create another relative document. When the doc status is set to other than confirmed I want to delete that relative document(if such exists). What's the best way to achieve this? To set if clause in the property set method or to fire event with the same if clause when the property's value have changed ?

Comment: What is your real problem? It feels like the answer to this is a matter of opinion. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask. What have you tried and why doesn't that work?

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I'm just asking what's the best approach to solve this.

Comment: it is a matter of choice. I will prefer to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface and raise the event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the behavior you want to achieve for your functionality.

1) **Using "If Clause" in set property:**
In this method, once you will compile your document class, you cannot change the behavior as the set property becomes hard-coded then. So, if the only thing that is to be done is to create and delete relative document, then this method is preferable.

2) **Creating events for change in "status" property:**
This functionality should be used in case when you want to decouple the action performed after any change in "status" property from your document class. If the business-logic to be executed after the "status" property is changed, is not decided at the time of compilation of document class, then this method is preferable.

The choice is yours!!

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely go for the event solution. This will decouple your solution more and it will make it possible to use the functionality from other places in your code more easily if that is someting you would like in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This depends very much on your application.
Generally, your model should (where I assume your document class belongs) should not contain business logic. It should only provide data and methods and callbacks that allow basic operations on data.

You should best [implement your own event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z57dxz2) and handle it in business logic in whichever way you need to.

Answer (score 0):

The "nice to have way" would be to generate an event and hook up a method to it that will create the other document. It would be a more explanatory way to see what you meant to do if someone else would service your code.